# How to load proper library in C# interative window

Tags: c#

I want to get `Input Local Identifier` information, so I tried to get by:

```
var keyboard = "00000409"
var id = LoadKeyboardLayout(keyboard, 1)
```

But this code ends up with error:

```
(1,10): error CS0103: The name 'LoadKeyboardLayout' does not exist in the current context
```

Probably I need to load a library for it. I'm not sure how it called in C#.

I'm running the code in C# interactive window and the version of it is:

```
Microsoft (R) Roslyn C# Compiler version 1.1.0.51109
Loading context from 'CSharpInteractive.rsp'.
```

How can I load proper library from interactive window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Platform Invoke to use this function, since it is a C++ function part of the Windows operating system.
Try to import this function as below:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr LoadKeyboardLayout(string pwszKLID, uint Flags);
```

Comment: I got a ` The type or namespace name 'DllImport' could not be found` error, but it can be fixed by `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`. The code works now fine. Thanks!